# R: Catch errors and continue execution after logging the stacktrace (no traceback available with tryCatch)

Tags: r, logging, error-handling

I have many unattended batch jobs in R running on a server and I have to analyse job failures after they have run.

I am trying to catch errors to log them and recover from the error gracefully but I am not able to get a stack trace (`traceback`) to log the code file name and line number of the R command that caused the error. A (stupid) reproducible example:

```
f <- function() {
  1 + variable.not.found    # stupid error
}

tryCatch( f(), error=function(e) {
  # Here I would log the error message and stack trace (traceback)
  print(e)            # error message is no problem
  traceback()         # stack trace does NOT work
  # Here I would handle the error and recover...
})
```

Running the code above produces this output:

> simpleError in f(): object 'variable.not.found' not found
>
> **No traceback available**

The traceback is not available and the reason is documented in the R help  (`?traceback`):

> Errors which are caught via try or tryCatch do not generate a
>   traceback, so what is printed is the call sequence for the last
>   uncaught error, and not necessarily for the last error.

In other words: Catching an error with `tryCatch` does kill the stack trace!

How can I

- handle errors **and**
- log the stack trace (traceback) for further examination
- [optionally] without using undocumented or hidden R internal functions that are not guaranteed to work in the future?

THX a lot!

Answer (score 9):

**Sorry for the long answer but I wanted to summarize all knowledge and references in one answer!**

## Main issues to be solved

1. `tryCatch` "unrolls" the call stack to the `tryCatch` call so that `traceback` and `sys.calls` do no longer contain the full stack trace to identify the source code line that causes an error or warning.
2. [`tryCatch` aborts the execution if you catch a warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836392/r-log-warnings-and-continue-execution) by passing a handler function for the `warning` condition. If you just want to log a warning you cannot continue the execution as normal.
3. `dump.frames` writes the evaluation environments (frames) of the stack trace to allow post-mortem debugging (= examining the variable values visible within each function call) but [`dump.frames` "forgets" to save the workspace too if you set the parameter `to.file = TRUE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421552/r-how-make-dump-frames-include-all-variables-for-later-post-mortem-debugging). Therefore important objects may be missing.
4. Find a simple logging framework since R does not support decent logging out of the box
5. Enrich the stack trace with the source code lines.

## Solution concept

1. Use `withCallingHandlers` instead of `tryCatch` to get a full stack trace pointing to the source code line that throwed an error or warning.
2. Catch warnings only within `withCallingHandlers` (not in `tryCatch`) since it just calls the handler functions but does not change the program flow.
3. Surround `withCallingHandlers` with `tryCatch` to catch and handle errors as wanted.
4. Use `dump.frames` with the parameter `to.file = FALSE` to write the dump into global variable named `last.dump` and save it into a file together with the global environment by calling `save.image`.
5. Use a logging framework, e. g. the package `futile.logger`.
6. R does track source code references when you set `options(keep.source = TRUE)`. You can add this option to your `.Rprofile` file or use a startup R script that sets this option and `source` your actual R script then.
7. To enrich the stack trace with the tracked source code lines you can use the undocumented (but widely used) function `limitedLabels`.
8. To filter out R internal function calls from stack trace you can remove all calls that have no source code line reference.

## Implementation

### Code template

Instead of using `tryCatch` you should use this code snippet:

```
library(futile.logger)

tryCatch(
  withCallingHandlers(<expression>,
    error = function(e) {
      call.stack <- sys.calls() # is like a traceback within "withCallingHandlers"
      dump.frames()
      save.image(file = "last.dump.rda")
      flog.error(paste(e$message, limitedLabels(call.stack), sep = "\n"))
    }
    warning = <similar to error above>
  }
  error = <catch errors and recover as you would do it normally>
  # warning = <...> # never do this here since it stops the normal execution like an error!
  finally = <your clean-up code goes here>
}
```

### Reusable implementation via a package (`tryCatchLog`)

I have implemented a simple package with all the concepts mentioned above.
It provides a function `tryCatchLog` using the `futile.logger` package.

Usage:

```
library(tryCatchLog)  # or source("R/tryCatchLog.R")

tryCatchLog(<expression>,
            error = function(e) {
              <your error handler>
            })
```

You can find the free source code at github:

https://github.com/aryoda/tryCatchLog

You could also `source` the [`tryCatchLog` function](https://github.com/aryoda/tryCatchLog/blob/master/R/tryCatchLog.R) instead of using a full blown package.

## Example (demo)

See the [demo file](https://github.com/aryoda/tryCatchLog/blob/master/demo/tryCatchLog_demo.R) that provides a lot of comments to explain how it works.

## References

### Other `tryCatch` replacements

- Logging of warnings and errors with with a feature to perform multiple attempts (retries) at try catch, e. g. for accessing an unreliable network drive:

  [Handling errors before warnings in tryCatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433848/handling-errors-before-warnings-in-trycatch)
- `withJavaLogging` function without any dependencies to other packages which also enriches the source code references to the call stack using `limitedLabels`:

  [Printing stack trace and continuing after error occurs in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975110/printing-stack-trace-and-continuing-after-error-occurs-in-r)

### Other helpful links

http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html

[A Warning About warning() - avoid R's warning feature](http://blog.obeautifulcode.com/R/A-Warning-About-Warning/)

[In R, why does withCallingHandlers still stops execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167959/in-r-why-does-withcallinghandlers-still-stops-execution)

[How to continue function when error is thrown in withCallingHandlers in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680623/how-to-continue-function-when-error-is-thrown-in-withcallinghandlers-in-r)

[Can you make R print more detailed error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485514/can-you-make-r-print-more-detailed-error-messages)

[How can I access the name of the function generating an error or warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984862/how-can-i-access-the-name-of-the-function-generating-an-error-or-warning)

[How do I save warnings and errors as output from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948361/how-do-i-save-warnings-and-errors-as-output-from-a-function/4952908#4952908)

[options(error=dump.frames) vs. options(error=utils::recover)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618796/optionserror-dump-frames-vs-optionserror-utilsrecover)

[General suggestions for debugging in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442518/general-suggestions-for-debugging-in-r)

[Suppress warnings using tryCatch in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785142/suppress-warnings-using-trycatch-in-r)

[R Logging display name of the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546356/r-logging-display-name-of-the-script)

[Background information about the "srcrefs" attribute (Duncan Murdoch)](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010-2/RJournal_2010-2_Murdoch.pdf)

[get stack trace on tryCatch'ed error in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15282471/get-stack-trace-on-trycatched-error-in-r)

Comment: I really wonder why some seemingly simple things are so complicated in R. Usually at the time when an exception handler is called, the call stack should be intact still; only when recovering from the error, some magic is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The `traceback` function can be used to print/save the current stack trace, but you have to specify an integer argument, which is the number of stack frames to omit from the top (can be `0`). This can be done inside a `tryCatch` block or anywhere else. Say this is the content of file `t.r`:

```
f <- function() {
    x <- 1
    g()
}
g <- function() {
    traceback(0)
}
```

When you source this file into R and run `f`, you get the stack trace:

> 3: traceback(0) at t.r#7 
>   2: g() at t.r#3 
>   1: f()

which has file name and line number information for each entry. You will get several stack frames originating from the implementation of `tryCatch` and you can't skip them by specifying a non-zero argument to `traceback`, yet indeed this will break in case the implementation of `tryCatch` changes.

The file name and line number information (source references) will only be available for code that has been parsed to keep source references (by default the `source`'d code, but not packages). The stack trace will always have call expressions.

The stack trace is printed by `traceback` (no need to call `print` on it).

For logging general errors, it is sometimes useful to use `options(error=)`, one then does not need to modify the code that causes the errors.

Comment: Thx for the detailled answer. My problem is still that the `traceback` is empty within a `tryCatch` handler and I want to log/print the traceback only in case of an error. If you modify your example by adding a line at the end of the f() function that causes an error (e. g. `stop("my error")`) and call f() via `tryCatch(f(), error=function(e) print(traceback()))` you still get nothing but a **"No traceback available"**. I am looking for a workaround for this.

Comment: Interesting behaviour, I think we have found a "dirty hack" in R's `traceback` or `tryCatch` implementation: While `traceback()` delivers "No traceback available" a `traceback(0)` delivers a full stack trace by omitting zero elements from the empty stack :-)

Comment: Still: `traceback(0)` delivers in the context of `tryCatch` the wrong stack trace (not the call hierarchy of error location but the call hierarchy of `sys.calls()` which does **not** point to the error line in the source file. Try it: 

`f <- function() {
  g()
  stop("error")
}
g <- function() {
  print("g")
}

tryCatch(f(), error=function(e) traceback(0))`

Comment: This is documented behavior, "traceback()" gives call stack of last uncaught error, "traceback(number)" gives current stack. Yes, you can get the same by sys.calls().

Comment: Full ACK, this strange semantics is documented: "The default display is of the stack of the last uncaught error ... If x is numeric, then the current stack is printed". Thanks for your feed back! I am playing around with `withCallingHandlers` currently which is promissing...