# Appending error messages to log file while running multiple script components in R

Tags: r, error-handling

I am attempting to write error messages for my script to a log file. It works when I do:

```
test <- file("error_file.log", open = "wt")
sink(test, type = "message")
try(data <- read.delim("genes2.txt",
                   header = TRUE,
                   as.is = TRUE))
sink(type = "message", append = TRUE)
close(test)
```

However, when I add an additional component to the script, it does not append both error messages. In this case both input files do not exist and should give a "no such file directory" for each file. Here is my attempt for both input files:

```
enter code heretest <- file("error_file.log", open = "wt")

sink(test, type = "message")

try(data <- read.delim("genes2.txt",
                       header = TRUE,
                       as.is = TRUE))

sink(type = "message", append = TRUE)
close(test)

test2 <- file("error_file.log", open = "wt")
sink(test2, type = "message")

try(variables <- read.delim("Book3.txt",
                            header = TRUE, 
                            as.is = TRUE,
                            check.names = FALSE,
                            text = TRUE,
                            na.strings = c("", NA)))

sink(type = "message", append = TRUE)
close(test2)
```

Thank you!

P.s. would it be possible to customize my own error messages for each try()?

Comment: Use `tryCatch` instead of `try` to catch and replace the error message, e. g.: `tryCatch(stop("stupid msg"), error = function(e) { if (grepl("stupid msg", e$message, fixed = TRUE)) print("clever msg") else print(e$message)})`. The risky part is that other R installations might emit error messages in different languages than English...

Comment: Could you perhaps give this example in the context of my script above. I am not sure where to place which function. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the valid answer of @suchait as basis you can customize your error message this way:

```
test <- file("error_file.log", open = "wt")
sink(test, append = TRUE, type = "message")

tryCatch(data <- read.delim("genes2.txt", header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE),
         error = function(e) {
           # replace one specific error message with another one
           if (grepl("cannot open", e$message, fixed = TRUE))
             # using "message" instead of "print" since you are sinking into type "message" (not "output")
             message("Customized error message 1: The file could not be opened\n")
           else
             message(e$message)
         }
         # If you wanted to replace the warnings too you will run into big problems:
         # tryCatch stops the execution and the error handler above is never called
         # causing the log to be empty. Conclusion: Don't reinvent the wheel and
         # use a suitable logging framework (e. g. the package "futile.logger")...
         # , warning = function(w) {return("Warning ignored...")}  # ignore warnings
)

tryCatch(variables <- read.delim("Book3.txt", header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, check.names = FALSE, text = TRUE, na.strings = c("", NA)),
         error = function(e) {
           # Always write your specific error message (+ the original message if you want)
           message(paste("Customized error message 2: The file could not be opened. Details:", e$message, "\n"))
         }
)

sink(type = "message")
```

If you wanted to replace the warnings too you will run into problems (see my comments in the code above) and the solution would be an even more complicated code (using `withCallingHandlers` + `try`)

Therefore I think it is better to use an existing logging framework like the package `futile.logger` (see function `ftry`) instead of reinventing the wheel and running into many problems. You can set the "severity level" then to log e. g. only errors but no warnings...

`tryCatch` is a beast in R if you want to combine error handling with logging (see [R: Catch errors and continue execution after logging the stacktrace (no traceback available with tryCatch)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39964040/4468078) for details and a long list of related SO questions)...

If you want to add automatic logging to `try` and `tryCatch` you could use the package `tryCatchLog` (https://github.com/aryoda/tryCatchLog). For compliance reasons: I am the author of the package...

Answer (score 1):

Try using this, it'll append both the messages to error_file.log:-

```
test <- file("error_file.log", open = "wt")
sink(test, append = TRUE, type = "message")


try(data <- read.delim("genes2.txt",
                       header = TRUE,
                       as.is = TRUE))


try(variables <- read.delim("Book3.txt",
                            header = TRUE, 
                            as.is = TRUE,
                            check.names = FALSE,
                            text = TRUE,
                            na.strings = c("", NA)))


sink(type = "message")
```

So, error file would have:-

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'genes2.txt': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'Book3.txt': No such file or directory
```

I hope this solves your problem.

The trick is just open your log file and sink once in the begining. And, close sink in the end.

Comment: Strange, when I tried that approach it did not work, now it does. Welcome to programming I guess. Do you have an idea for custom messages?

Comment: Please accept answer if it solved your problem. Custom messages as in?

Comment: Sorry about that. Instead of the whole: In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'Book3.txt': No such file or directory. I would make the error something like: "Please check your input file". into the error_file.log.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you would need `gsub` to customize your messages.